# Mixed Quantifiers and Not

Tags: logic

How do I read the following expressions? I understand how to read them when the not isn't there, but the presence of the not makes it hard to understand.
$
\\ \not \exists x\  \forall y\ F(x, y) \tag{1} 
$
$
\\ \not \exists y\  \forall x\ F(x, y) \tag{2} 
$
$
\\ \forall y\  \not \exists x\ F(x, y) \tag{3} 
$
$
\\ \forall x\  \not \exists y\ F(x, y) \tag{4} 
$

To clarify, what I don't understand is how I would sort of translate this to English.

Comment: I read it like there doesn't exist a $x$ such that for all $y$,  $F(x,y)$ is true.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: I don't understand why @PNDas's comment doesn't answer your question.  What more are you looking for?

Comment: For example, $
\\ \forall x\   \exists y\ F(x, y) 
$ can be read as every element maps to something. How do I read this when it is $
\\ \forall x\  \not \exists y\ F(x, y)
$

Comment: $\forall x\not\exists yF(x,y)$ is just $\forall x\lnot\exists y F(x,y)$ i.e. for any $x$ it's not the case that exists some $x$ such that $F(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\not \exists x= \neg \exists x$ which translates as "there exists no $x$".

Perhaps it is easiest to insert for the predicate symbol $F(x,y)$ something English like "x knows y". Then we have:

- $\not \exists x \forall y F(x,y)$ = Noone knows everyone = Everyone has someone they don't know
- $\not \exists y \forall x F(x,y)$ = Noone is known by everyone = Everyone has someone who dosen't know them
- $\forall y \not \exists x F(x,y)$ = Everyone doesn't have anyone who knows them = Nooone is known by anyone
- $\forall x \not \exists y F(x,y)$ = Everyone doesn't have anyone they know = Noone knows anyone